# Get list of properties and values from PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have access to a 3rd party PropertyGrid within my application (C#. ,Net v2).  Is there an easy way to iterate over the properties in the grid and their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'll need to use reflection on the SelectedObject property to get all of the properties and values.  The grid itself doesn't programmatically expose those.